# How to import a standard header into swift

Tags: swift

I use a few imports with `#if` statements like the following:

```
#if IOS
 import UIKit
#endif
```

I rather not have to repeat this in every swift file. Is there a way to import this from a separate file?

Comment: Probably in the bridging header would be a good place.